# C# linq-to-sql. Concat with order

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, concatenation

I have 2 `linq-to-sql` queries in `C#`, from Table1 (id, itemid, date) and Table2 (id, itemid, date) and I am using `concat` between them but the dates are not ordered.
How I can order the result date-wise?

Comment: If you post some code, I can make my answer more useful for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) clause, or an [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx) clause.

Comment: when you work several hours the most obvious solution is not that obvious.... thank you